# Prove that the function is not a contraction and show it is not a contradiction of the contractive mapping theorem

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Prove the function $K$ is defined by $K(x) = 4x(1-x)$ maps the interval $[0,1]$ into itself and it is not a contraction. Prove that it has a fixed point. Why does this not contradict the Contraction Mapping Theorem?

I understand how to show that it maps the interval into itself, how to show it has a fixed point, and that it is not a contraction. I am confused about the Contraction Mapping Theorem part.

Answer (score 2):

It's really logic:

> Contraction mapping principle: **If** $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is a contraction, **then** it has a fixed point.

Your example just showed the [converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) of the above statement:

> **If** $f : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ has a fixed point, **then** it is a contraction.

is not true. As the converse of a statement is not the same as that statement, your example does not contradict the contraction mapping principle.